# Different behaviour with std::unordered_map container on Windows and Linux

Tags: c++, c++11, unordered-map

For my program I need to have unordered key. To do the job done I use std::unordered_map container. Here's a test code :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::unordered_map<std::string, int> toto;

    toto["Outlook"] = 454;
    toto["Temperature"] = 4;
    toto["Humidity"] = 554;
    toto["Wind"] = 545454;

    std::unordered_map<std::string, int>::iterator It = toto.begin();

    std::cout << toto.size() << std::endl;

    for (; It != toto.end(); ++It)
        std::cout << (*It).first << std::endl;
    getchar();
    return (0);
}
```

On windows (Visual Studio 2012) the ouput is :

```
Outlook
Temperature
Humidity
Wind
```

It's correctly. None sort has been applied.

But on Linux the output is the following :

```
Humidity
Outlook
Wind
Temperature
```

PS : On linux I compile my program with -std::c++0x and -std=gnu++0x and there is no compilation error.

So, how is possible to have a different behaviour with the same program ?
Thanks in advance for your help !

Comment: It's unordered. Why do you care about the order?

Comment: @chris as far I know, unordered_map uses the hash result as the index of the element in the internal container. `std::unordered_map` iterators are the iterators of that container, so when you do a trasversal through the unordered_map, you really trasverse that internal container. So, **different orders means different hash results, or different allocation policies?**

Comment: @chris My point is (and OP question goal, I think): **Why the two versions (executions) have different orders?** Thats interesting

Comment: The order is not guaranteed in any way. I can't tell you what exactly each implementation does differently (but it shouldn't be hard to find since it's a class template), but whatever it is, it's allowed to give different results.

Comment: @Manu343726: A different implementation. A different phase of the moon. A different number of goats. The order is undefined, and that's that. There's nothing more to understand about it.

Comment: [My unordered_map has different orders on Windows and Linux! Outrageous!](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/11649852#11649852)

Comment: So you are wondering why an unordered container has different orders on different implementations compiled using different compilers running on different operating systems?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`unordered_map` is usually (read practically always) implemented with a hash table, which by default uses `std::hash` to select which bucket to place an item in.

There are many different hash functions, so what you are seeing is that the two different standard libraries implementation of `std::hash` on Windows and Linux use two different hash functions - which produce different hash codes - that in turn produce different bucket placement, and hence different orderings when iterated.

I would spend some time studying the [hash table data structure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) in general if you don't understand what this means.  Hashing is a really cool and useful mathematical tool in many aspects of programming.

Comment: In addition, even with the same hash function and hash value, the current number of buckets influences the item placement too.

Comment: Correct, in addition, the two implementations might use different load factors or collision resolution strategies which will also effect the iteration order.

Answer (score 4):

As the name (unordered_map) implies - the container is unordered. No one makes any guarantees as to what the order of the items will be and truly - each implementation has a different order.