# Ordered iterator of C++11 unordered map<int, Mytype*>

Tags: c++, c++11

As the question says, I need to iterate over my map's elements in a certain order, that is, the traditional < order. I thought that by using integers as key, it would have been done automatically, but I was wrong. In fact, when I use a for-each loop like this:

```
mymap<int, Mytype*> m; 
for(auto&x: m){
std::cout << x->first;
}
```

The keys aren't in order! Why does that happen?It's iterator's fault or maybe it's because of 
the hashing function?

EDIT:now I've noticed that if I change the order of insertion it changes the result of the for-each loop too.

EDIT2: I know unordered_map is unordered. But:
"Internally, the elements in the unordered_map are not sorted in any particular order with respect to either their key or mapped values, but organized into buckets depending on their hash values to allow for fast access to individual elements directly by their key values (with a constant average time complexity on average)."(from c++reference)

So I thought I could use a particular Hash function that could give also the order(since keys are int)

Comment: Uh...but you have...uh...read the word *"unordered"* in there, haven't you?

Comment: Is it unordered_map or map?

Comment: Reminds me of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18658987/different-behaviour-with-stdunordered-map-container-on-windows-and-linux#comment27476659_18658987

Comment: Sounds like you either need to switch to `map` instead of `unordered_map`, or extract the keys into an array/vector, sort the array/vector, and then use the sorted keys to reference the map values in the order you want. One of those sounds a bit easier than the other...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't get order out of an `std::unordered_map`, you can't really write an ordered iterator for it, unless you really hack the concept.

If you want ordered iteration, either store it in a `std::map`, which is ordered, but likely slower in accessing, or either copy the contents, or create indexing into a different container, sort it (or use a sorted container like `std::map`), and use that data. You either re-create this data each time you need it ordered, or keep the two containers in sync. For this the best choice would be to use `boost::multi_index_container`. Reference: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0b1/libs/multi_index/doc/index.html

Answer (score 3):

From the title of your question I assume that `mymap` is `unordered_map`. Well, `unordered_map` is unordered. The order of entries does not follow from `operator<` or anything like that, and you may assume that the order is random. The map iterators reflect this internal order.